# What does `each` method return?

Tags: ruby

When I call

```
@data.each do |d|
  some code here
end
```

what does the `each` method return? An array of objects? Or more generally, what does `do`...`end` block take?

Comment: [Documentation](http://rdoc.sourceforge.net/doc/) says .. what?

Comment: It's an instance variable from the controller. For example, @books = Book.all I don't know what specific structure it is

Comment: Then you'd better find out .. I am voting as Not a Real question because once the type is known then it's just "What is Array#each?" or "What is Hash#each?" or "What is x#each?" which are covered in the appropriate reference material. (It's from [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/), well, there is documentation for that too.)

Comment: Also, a quick log of `@data.class.name` will show what class it is.  There's a lot of stuff Ruby will tell you without even having to open the docs.

Comment: `.each` will return the receiver, which may be mutated by an operation in the block: `a = [[1], [2], [3]]; a = a.each {|x| x[0] += 1}; a` returns `[[2], [3], [4]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It iterates over the members of the enumerable object. So if `@data` is an array it will return the elements of the array one at a time as `d`. Exact behavior depends on the type of object. See the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-each)

`Books.all` returns a object, that although it is not an array, behaves like one in this case.

Answer (score 3):

- `each` returns the receiver, in this case `@data`.
- The `do` ... `end` is a block.

Answer (score 0):

The `each` method will run the block (using the method `yield`) once for each value in data.  This is called an iterator.  For an array it will iterate over all the values in the array, for a hash it will run once per every pair of (key,value).  You can define your own iterator for your own classes.

The return value of `each` depends on the object it is invoked.  When invoked on an array it will return the array.

In your case the method `each` will execute the block once per each value and send each value as a parameter to the block.

For example-

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.each do |n|
    p n
end
```

is just the same as

```
p a[0]
p a[1]
p a[2]
```